# If $A \bigtriangleup B = C \bigtriangleup B$, then $A=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the power set $P$ of any set $A$ becomes an abelian group under the operation of symmetric difference so symmetric difference has this property. However, I need another solution.
I tried to prove it using operations on sets.
Here's my attempt:
$$A \bigtriangleup B = C \bigtriangleup B$$
$$(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)=(C\cup B)\setminus(C\cap B)$$
$$(A\cup B) \cap (A_c \cup B_c)=(C \cup B) \cap (C_c \cup B_c)$$
$$(A\cap B_c) \cup (B\cap A_c)=(C\cap B_c) \cup (C\cap A_c)$$
I was thinking about doing \ $\cap B$ but it doesn't get me anywhere.
If there is another way of solving this, without set operations, it would be helpful as well.

Comment: Going by contradiction will be far easier in my opinion.  Suppose that $A\triangle B=C\triangle B$.  Suppose also that $x\in A\setminus C$.  Show then that $x$ would have been an element of exactly one of $A\triangle B$ or $C\triangle B$ but not both, a contradiction.  Repeat the argument for $C$ to learn that $A=C$.

Comment: Hint: Symmetric difference is associative, and $X\triangle X=\varnothing$.

Comment: So that would be: $A \bigtriangleup (A \bigtriangleup B)= A \bigtriangleup (C \bigtriangleup B)$, $B=(A \bigtriangleup C) \bigtriangleup B$ therefore $A \bigtriangleup C= \emptyset $ and $A=C$?

Comment: @Squidward: Why not use $B$, since it appears in both expressions, instead?

Comment: Sure, it would simplify it a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Can you show that, for all $B$, $B \triangle B = \emptyset$?

Then you'll have

$$\begin{align}
A \triangle B = C \triangle B
&\iff (A \triangle B) \triangle B = (C \triangle B) \triangle B\\
&\iff A \triangle (B \triangle B) = C \triangle (B \triangle B)\\
&\iff A \triangle \emptyset = C \triangle \emptyset \\
&\iff A = C
\end{align}$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks! $B \bigtriangleup B= \emptyset$ is trivial since $B$ \ $B= \emptyset$

Comment: you've got it ^_^